# Long term behaviour of the solution to a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following problem:

> We're looking at the system of differential equations:
>   $$y'=\frac{1}{2}
>    \left({\begin{array}{cc}
>    \lambda_1+\lambda_2 & \lambda_1-\lambda_2 \\
>    \lambda_1-\lambda_2 & \lambda_1+\lambda_2 \\
>   \end{array} } \right)y 
> $$ with $y(0)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    z_1  \\
>    z_2  \\
>   \end{array} } \right]$
>   and $c_1=\frac{1}{2}(z_1+z_2)$, $c_2=\frac{1}{2}(z_1-z_2).$ It has the exact solution y and u got calculated by the explicite Euler-method:
>   $$y(t)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    c_1 & c_2 \\
>    c_1 & -c_2 \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    e^{\lambda_1t} \\
>    e^{\lambda_2t} \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
> $$and$$
> u_j=
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    c_1 & c_2 \\
>    c_1 & -c_2 \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    (1+h\lambda_1)^j \\
>    (1+h\lambda_2)^j
>   \end{array} } \right]
> $$
>   Now let $\lambda_1<0$,$\lambda_2<0$ and $|\lambda_2|>>|\lambda_1|$

I have two problems:

> 1.) Which $\lambda_i$ determines the long term behaviour of the solution y for t$\rightarrow \infty$?

So basically, we want to know which $\lambda_i$ is more important for the value of y for t$\rightarrow \infty.$
I believe it is $\lambda_1$, because it is closer to $0$. $\lambda_2$ is far bigger than $\lambda_1$, so the solution is only really dependant on $\lambda_1$. Is my idea correct? If so, I don't know how to write an actual answer.

> 2.) Through which $\lambda_i$ is the step-size h determined?

I have no idea on this one, because I don't know why h is dependant on the $\lambda_i$. Could someone help me here?

Comment: 1) $e^{\lambda_1t}>>e^{\lambda_2t}$ for $t >> \frac{lambda_2}{lambda_1}$. For a proof, simply look at the ratios of the two exponentials. 2) $|1+h\lambda_i| < 1$ for stability of the Euler method. So pick the more constraining $\lambda_i$ that satisfies those constraints simultaneously